# Menu of triggers reveal corresponding dialog elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have this code that for the most part, does what it needs to do, but I'm having trouble making it more concise and elegant.

**[Codepen](http://codepen.io/modermo/pen/mEbypN?editors=0010)**

Intended functionality:

- If you click a trigger, it's corresponding element must display
- If you click another trigger, that trigger's element displays and the other closes
- If you click the trigger whilst it is open, it simply closes the element

Any ideas on how to make this cleaner?

```
var trigger = ".trigger";
var recipient = ".target";
var not_trigger = $(".trigger").not(this);


$(trigger).click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  recipient = '#' + $(this).attr('data-target-id');
  var not_recipient = $(".target").not(recipient);

  if($(trigger).hasClass("active")){
    $(trigger).not(this).removeClass("active");
  }
  $(this).toggleClass("active") ;

  if($(".target").hasClass("open")){
    $(not_recipient).removeClass("open");
    TweenMax.to($(".target"), .3, {display:'none', y:'0%', autoAlpha:0});

    if($(recipient).hasClass("open")){
      $(recipient).removeClass("open");
      TweenMax.to(recipient, .3, {display:'none', y:'0%', autoAlpha:0});
    }else{
      $(recipient).addClass("open");
      TweenMax.to(recipient, .3, {display:'block', y:'100%', autoAlpha:1});
    }
  }else {
    $(recipient).addClass("open");
    TweenMax.to(recipient, .3, {display:'block', y:'100%', autoAlpha:1});
  }

});
```

Comment: Is there a benefit in making variables containing the class-names as strings? Then using these variables instead of $('.trigger') etc. directly? Or is it just a writing-preference?

Comment: Is e.stopPropagation() really needed here? Moreover: Variable 'not_trigger' is unused.